# jquery datepicker only works on <input type=text> within Chrome?

Tags: jquery

I have a very simple page that's using jquery's datepicker.  I have:

```
<input id=datepicker type=image src='cal.png'>
```

When I click on the image in FF/IE, it works as expected, but does not work in Chrome (ver. 4.1.249.1064).  However if I simply change to "`type=text`", it works within Chrome.

So my question is this: am I allowed to use Datepicker with "`type=image`"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-buttonImageOnly

I think you want to use the buttonImageOnly option for the datepicker.  You may need to create  a text or hidden input to hold the value, if you are wanting to only display cal.png with out a text input for the selected date.

Comment: That worked great, thanks!  Changed to "type=hidden",

then added this to my defintion function:
{ showOn: 'button',
buttonImage: '/images/tiny_cal.png',
buttonImageOnly: 'true' }

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
<input id="datepicker" type="image" src='cal.png'>
```

Not sure if you need it but wrap the names in quote marks